# Convert styles to Mapnik 3 XML

Tags: mapnik, ordnance-survey

I am using Ordnance Survey's [OpenMap - Local](https://osdatahub.os.uk/downloads/open/OpenMapLocal) in Mapnik 3.0.

Ordnance Survey make stylesheets available here:

https://github.com/OrdnanceSurvey/OS-OpenMap-Local-stylesheets

Is there a way to convert any of these formats (ESRI, GML or Geopackage) into the XML I need for Mapnik?

Or alternatively, is there a way to get Mapnik to read any of these formats directly?

Comment: quite old geotools2 to mapnik "Convert SLD used by geotools/geoserver into mapnik xml" https://github.com/springmeyer/geotools2mapnik

Comment: Thanks @Mapperz this might work but looks too Alpha for my requirements, and I'm using Mapnik 3 rather than Mapnik 2. Thank you for flagging it though, from what I can see it is the closest solution!